# Page numbers invisible in resume class

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, resume

I have a quite weird problem with resume class (`res.cls`). I am typing my resume but I do not see the page numbers. I just want simple plain page numbers at the end of each page, i.e., the standard format that you get once you type a latex document.

I think the numbers should be there for all documents. Thus, it might be the case that they are invisible due to some issue.

How can I display the numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`res.cls` internally issues

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Simply change the page style by writting

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

in the preamble.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\pagestyle{plain} 
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly works! Thanks a lot for the great answer!

Comment: @safak You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer (if you consider it solved your problem) by clicking on the checkmark to its left :-) In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).